# Opening Spyder from a Python 2 Environment still runs Python 3 in Spyder

Tags: python, linux, anaconda, spyder

I have created a new environment, specifying the Python version as 2.7. This has worked correctly as when I activate the environment and I run on the command line:

```
python --version
```

It returns:

```
Python 2.7.15
```

However, when I then open Spyder from the command line in the same environment, Spyder is still using Python 3. I was expecting the Python version in Spyder to match the Python version in the environment. So what could be stopping it working as I expected? I am on Linux Ubuntu on a virtual machine.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you are launching it from the wrong environment.

**Assuming you're using Anaconda**, you should activate the py2 environment and launch spyder from it, but being sure to have installed it in there before.
Here a simple sequence as example:

1. Create a new env py2 based

```
>conda create -n <NAME_OF_YOUR_ENV> python=2.7
```

2. activate the environment

```
>activate <NAME_OF_YOUR_ENV>
```

3. install Spyder

```
<NAME_OF_YOUR_ENV> >conda install spyder
```

4. launch spyder

```
<NAME_OF_YOUR_ENV> >spyder
```

It should be enough

Answer (score 0):

Do you have several python installed on your system? I guess you have 2.7.15 installed by default with your system and you installed python 3 (via Anaconda?) without adding it in your path.
Are you in spyder's directory when you launch it (and launch spyder with `./spyder`)?

Comment: Yes your assumptions are correct. I am not in spyder's directory when launching and not launching with    ./spyder

Answer (score 0):

It seems I missed a step to install the Spyder package within the environment.

```
conda install spyder
```

It works as expected now.